Deduce a template class with reduced number of template parameters
I have a wrapper class which takes a template<typename> class as a parameter. However, I have a class with extra parameters, such as template<typename T, typename P> Special, and I would like to fit it into the parameter of the wrapper class.
The only solution I can figure out is like the following:
// test.cpp
// Base class
class Base
{
  public:
    int data_base = 1;
};

// A derive class
template<typename P>
class Derived : public Base
{
    P data_child;
};

// A wrapper to accept any type similar to Derived<P> as the base class
template<template<typename> class BT, typename P>
class Wrapper : public BT<P>
{
    int do_something;
};

// However, a special derived class need an extra template parameter
template<typename T, typename P>
class Special : public Derived<P>
{
    T special;
};

// Try to fit Special into the type of BT of Wrapper
template<typename T>
class SpecialBridge
{
  public:
    template<typename P>
    using BT = Special<T, P>;
};

// actually define the type to use (Error!)
template<typename T, typename P>
using Actual = Wrapper<SpecialBridge<T>::BT, P>;

int main()
{
    Actual<int, int> obj;
    return obj.data_base;
}

However, both c++17 and c++20 claim the same. The compiler cannot deduct the type of SpecialBridge<T>::BT
$ g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test
test.cpp:40:47: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class> class BT, class P> class Wrapper’
   40 | using Actual = Wrapper<SpecialBridge<T>::BT, P>;
      |                                               ^
test.cpp:40:47: note:   expected a class template, got ‘SpecialBridge<T>::BT’
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:44:3: error: ‘Actual’ was not declared in this scope
   44 |   Actual<int, int> obj;
      |   ^~~~~~
test.cpp:44:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
   44 |   Actual<int, int> obj;
      |          ^~~
test.cpp:45:10: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
   45 |   return obj.data_base;
      |          ^~~

Is there any way I can do this properly? Sorry for my not-so-standard way of describing this problem. The example code is more or less self-explainable.

Why not just change wrapper's first parameter to template<template<typename...> class BT ?

Working demo after changing the first parameter to template<typename...>. Or even this demo

Wrapper provides parameter P for BT. When Special is used, I hope to have something like Wrapper<Special<T>, P>, where T comes directly with Special but P is provided at the point of actual use. Would this be possible with typename...? Please elaborate.

You can change wrapper to template<template<typename...> class BT, typename... P>class Wrapper : public BT<P...>  {};. Then you can just write Wrapper<Special, int, int> w;

Most of Derived classes are with a single parameter P, only the Special one needs two parameters. The code in Wrapper class should be shared by all derived or special classes. (I do not want multiple wrapper class) The working demo asks all derived and special classes to have two parameters!

You can limit the number of parameter to be maximum of 2. Also, the code I provided wil also work for other derived class with single P.

I see. This seems to work. I need go back to actual project and see whether it nails the problem. Would you like to draw a simple answer. I will certain accept it once it is proven working. Many thanks!

I've added it as an answer. Note the use of requires(sizeof...(P)<=2) to check we don't pass more than 2 parameters to P. You can remove it if you don't need it. It is trivial to change it to c++11 code.

You can make use of parameter packs as shown below:
template<template<typename...> class BT, typename... P> requires(sizeof...(P)<=2)
class Wrapper: public BT<P...>  
{
  int do_something;
};
int main() {

    Wrapper<Special, int, int> w;
    return w.data_base;
}

Working demo

From the error message:
note:   expected a class template, got 'SpecialBridge<T>::BT'

it is clear, that the compiler couldn't understand the SpecialBridge<T>::BT is a template in the alias you defined.
Therefore, the template keyword is necessary because BT is a dependent name (it depends on the template parameter T).
template<typename T, typename P>
using Actual = Wrapper<SpecialBridge<T>::template BT, P>;
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^  ---> add this!

Now, your code will work as expected: See live demo
